# I'm developing iPhone web based app

Tags: iphone, json, geolocation, titanium

So when I type something in the search bar of my app, it should send my latitude and longitude to the web server, so it can return me the nearest place where I can get the searched tag. I'm new to Titanium so can anyone help me?

Comment: learn titanium first. and what you had tried first?

Comment: Are you getting your current lat, long from the device?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically sending a request via HTTP to your webservice and use the result (Take the function from @Muhammad Zeeshan to get longitude/latitude):

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
// write file on success
xhr.onload = function(){
    var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,this.apiFile);
    f.write(this.responseData);
};
// error handling
xhr.onerror = function(){  
    Ti.API.error(this.status + ' - ' + this.statusText);  
};
// open the client (and test HTTPS)
xhr.open('GET','http://example.com/api/?longitude=' + longitude + '&latitude=' + latitude);
// send the data
xhr.send();
// read file and return json
var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, this.apiFile);
var contents = f.read();
var yourJson = JSON.parse(contents);
```

On the server Side you need some Webservice to talk to (you didn't specify  a language you use on the server), but I presume you get the data via a MySQL database (others should be similar):

```
SELECT ((ACOS(SIN($lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS($latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(($longitude – lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` FROM `locations` HAVING `distance`<=’10′ ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

Add additional WHERE clauses to filter by tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [TiStudio](http://my.appcelerator.com) instead of TiDeveloper you can use the sample project GPS to start with. It's bundled in the download so just fire it up and use that code as a working copy to learn from.